# jQuery data() pass this & object into it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        name : 'benjamin'
    };

    function EasyZoom(target, options) {
        this.$target = $(target);       
        this.opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options, this.$target.data()); //why extend this.$target.data()?
        this._init();
    }

    EasyZoom.prototype._init = function() {
        this.printout();
    };

    EasyZoom.prototype.printout = function(){
        console.log(this.opts); 
    };

    $.fn.easyZoom = function(options){
        $.data(this, 'easyZoom', new EasyZoom(this, options));  //isn't $.data(name, value) only?, why $.data(this, 'name', object)?
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('div').easyZoom({name: 'benny'});
});
```

I'm new in create jQuery plugin, I try to learn the style of easyZoom plugin. However I got few question I don't understand

1. `$.data();` ins't data param should be `name & value`, why in easyZoom plugin use `this, name, object`
2. `$.extend();` why extend `$target.data();` object into defaults?
3. why store new object inside of data? why not just `var foo = new EasyZoom(this, options);`

Comment: According to the documentation, [`$.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) takes 3 parameters when setting a value, and 2 parameters when getting a value. I think you're confusing it with [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: oh I did confuse, I didnt know there is another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is `$.data(elem, key, value)` but not `$.data(name, value)`.

Second, `$.extend()` likes merge.

For an example,

```
$.extend({}, {'foo': '1'}, {'hoge': '2'}) => {'foo': '1', 'hoge': '2'}
```

You can check the docs of jQuery.

[$.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

[$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: I know extend is merge, my question is why merge $target.data()

Comment: @BenjaminW merge `$target.data()` can make user pass options by `data-*`, such as `<div data-name="foo"></div>`. Then `$target.data()` will get `{name: 'foo'}`

Comment: one more question why store new object inside of data? why not just var foo = new EasyZoom(this, options);

Comment: ok i get it now, so user can pass data from tag instead $.({name : 'foo'})